# ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm new to using VS Code for Python and can't seem to even start as there's some problem with the python path that only shows up in VSCode. The sample code works when keying in interactively to python3, pyCharm and calling via `python3 test.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import geoip2.database
print(sys.path)  
reader = geoip2.database.Reader('/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb')
response = reader.city('78.31.107.133')
print (response.country.iso_code)
```

errors out with 
ImportError: No module named geoip2.database

it's definitely there via pip and in

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

and sys.path prints

`['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg']`

Any ideas what i'm missing?

Comment: perhaps the wrong version? Try installing `ipython` and start a new `ipython` shell. The type `import geoip2` and tell me what the result is.

Comment: have you tried changing your shebang to be `#!/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: turns out that i had a manually installed version conflicting with the version brought in via brew. I nuked the manually installed version and relinked the brew version and all is well in the world.

Answer (score 1):

turns out that i had a manually installed version conflicting with the version brought in via brew. I nuked the manually installed version and relinked the brew version and all is well in the world